# How to count patches on the left or right side of the turtle?

Tags: netlogo

How to count patches on the left or right side of the turtle? I know the following code is wrong, but something is like that. Thanks

```
count patches with [pcolor = green] [pxcor < xcor]
```

Comment: Worked it out by myself.

    count patches in-radius 3 with [pcolor = green and pxcor < [ xcor ] of myself]
    
    count patches in-radius 3 with [ pcolor = green and pxcor > [ xcor ] of myself]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity's sake, I'll put the answer you got as a full answer.  Basically you need to use "myself" here (see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself)

```
ask turtle 0 [ count patches with [ pxcor < [ xcor ] of myself ] ]
```